# Wordpress CPT Taxonomy Page Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

This has been asked lots of times in stackoverflow but I'm doing everything and nothing works I still get "Oops! That page can’t be found."

I got a template where I loop the CPT taxonomies with the link
[[image]]

When I click one of the categories I get the URL

```
http://comisionpais.com/categorias/educacion/
http://comisionpais.com/categorias/{taxonomy}
```

I got this files created

```
taxonomy-comision-publicaciones.php
taxonomy.php
category-publica.php
category.php
```

and this is the code for the 3 CPT I'm using

```
/****************** Custom Post Type ***************/


// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'publica',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Publicaciones' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Publicación' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'publicacion'),
            // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail' ),
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'page',
            'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-book',
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'entrev',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Entrevistas' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Entrevista' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'entrevista'),
            // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail' ),
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'page',
            'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-video-alt3',
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'reco',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Reconocimientos' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Reconocimiento' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'reconocimiento'),
            // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail' ),
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'page',
            'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-awards',
        )
    );
}

// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

/****** CPT Category Link ******/

function create_comision_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, // Set this to 'false' for non-hierarchical taxonomy (like tags)
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'categorias' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'comision-publicaciones', array( 'publica' ), $args );
    register_taxonomy( 'comision-entrevistas', array( 'entrev' ), $args );
    register_taxonomy( 'comision-reconocimientos', array( 'reco' ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_comision_taxonomies', 0 );
```

So I'm concerned if I got wrong the naming of the files, but with all I've read if I use the main file name like taxonomy.php or category.php will use those files but nothing is happening.

[image]

Comment: Have you run this query in functions.php which might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153635/custom-posts-with-same-slug-redirecting-to-wrong-post-with-same-slug/42222611?noredirect=1#comment71737254_42222611

Comment: Not working, or not sure if i'm doing it right !!! but thanks for try I appreciate. @MohammadAshiqueAli

Comment: EDIT: Changed the 'rewrite'  => array( 'slug' => 'categorias' ),
to  'rewrite' => true, and worked the hell well.... I got that from that link you gave me,cheers @MohammadAshiqueAli

Comment: You use a same rewrite URL at taoxnomies `array( 'slug' => 'categorias' )`. I think it is wrong