# Without base slug CPT is not working with AMP

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I have created custom post type "services" and "quotation" but when i removed CPT base slug from url, amp pages are not working.

For example (working if): mysite.com/cpt_base_slug/post_name

For example (not working if): mysite.com/post_name

Please help me in this regards.

Comment: Have you updated the permalink ?

Comment: This may help you ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153635/custom-posts-with-same-slug-redirecting-to-wrong-post-with-same-slug/42222611#42222611

Comment: yes i have updated permalink. post types not working with AMP.